# Use custom SqlMembershipProvider to store users (and roles) in Cache?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, caching, asp.net-membership

i'm developing a "small" warehouse-management WebApplication for few users(5-10 parralel) but with a complex authorization system(checking if pages,menus,TabPanels, UserControls and even single controls are visible or enabled) and permanent and frequent access. Because i've only limited experiences with the ASP.Net MembershipProvider, i'm unsure what's the best approach for following goal:

I want to hold all users, roles and frequently used masterdata in the Cache(in a Dataset). Hence every readonly access should be faster and causes less traffic than always using the database. On updates,deletes and inserts i would update the cached dataset and also the database.

Can i use or extend the SqlMembershipProvider to achieve this goal and if possible how?
Should i use the stored-procedures from asp.net or simply use the standard `CreateUser`, `GetUser`, `DeleteUser`-functionality? Does this approach makes sense at all?

Performance is a key factor because users are paid by piece rate.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably extend the SqlMembershipProvider and make passthrough calls that cache the data.

I'm not familiar with "users are paid by piece rate".  Are you trying to save data being transferred from the data?  Data transferred from the webserver to the client?  CPU cycles?

Comment: I'm not sure if  "users are paid by piece rate" is the correct english term. Users will scan units(mobiles), validate them and get money from the toal count. So if the application is a bottleneck, they'll get less money ;)

Comment: Got it.  So basically the application just needs the fastest response time possible.

Comment: Because it's a pretty incomplete answer. half comment/half question kind of thing.